# Android Studio: Shared device development

Tags: android, android-studio

We are developing several apps for Android, and it is annoying when we have to trade testing hardware and get the 'you need to uninstall an app' to install a work in progress version of an app for testing.

Is there a way to share the developer key/signature between several developer machines so we all can over-install each others app versions.

Comment: You can't share debug key because it's dependent on the machine it's generated while installing android studio so another option is using a certificate which you use for signing your application share with trusted developers/person and test your application in release build. if you found any other solution post here it will be helpful for other developers.

Comment: Yes you can share the debug.keystore file and will work ok